# Linebreak in index

Tags: line-breaking, makeindex

I have to set up an index of persons. Many have birthplaces with duplicate names, e.g. Immanuel Kant was born in Königsberg which nowadays is named Kalinigrad. So his entry would look like:

```
Kant, Immanuel (Königsberg/Kaliningrad 1724 – Königsberg/Kalinigrad 1804)
```

Now I try to achieve an automatic linebreak if necessary after "Königsberg/". I know normally i could use two quotes "" to have it split like this:

```
Kant, Immanuel (Königsberg/
Kaliningrad 1724 – Königsberg/ 
Kaliningrad 1804)
```

But this doesn't work. My WE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[texindy, splitindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[program=texindy,options=-L german-DIN]


\makeindex[name=pw, title=Personen und Werke, columns=2, intoc]
\newcommand\pwindex[1]{\index[pw]{#1}}

\begin{document}
Word\pwindex{AAAAAAA BBBBB/CCCCCC/DDDDD/EEEEE/FFFFF}             

\printindex[pw]                                      
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\slash` instead of `/`. By the way, it is Kaliningrad.

Comment: It works! I agree it is a duplicate though not when it comes to indices.